# magento 1.9 Unable to login its redirecting like index.php/admin/index/index/key/cd1208995019ddc94f96b103e34b64d2/

Tags: magento

I tried to login magneto admin dashboard https://chrischristensen.in/admin it after submit its not showing admin dashboard only changing key key/cd1208995019ddc94f96b103e34b64d2

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear cookies in the browser or open in an incognito window. There must be an issues with the cookies for your domain.

Comment: Thanks for replay, I tried to login via incognito window it showing like same Can you please help

Comment: Sure, can you send me screenshot of cookie path settings from backend at System > Configuration > General > Web > Session Cookie Management.